# Decoding return bytes from Solidity `address.call`

Tags: solidity, evm

If I call method `x`, which returns an `address`, in the Ethereum contract with address `addr`:

```
(bool success, bytes memory returnVal) = addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("x()"));
require(success, "Could not call x()");
```

I then need to decode the result in `returnBytes` to get an address. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
(address returnedAddr) = abi.decode(returnVal, (address));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The call data must be composed of a function identifier (4 first bytes of keccak256 of your function signature) followed by the encoded parameters if any. `addr.call(abi.encodePacked("x()"))` is incorrect. The best way is to use the provided `abi` functions, such as `encodeWithSignature`, it's just more readable.

Like in the following example. I just changed `call` to `staticcall` to be able to keep the `test` function view. You can change it to `call` if that's a better fit for your use case.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {
    function getAddress() public pure returns (address) {
        return 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    }
}
contract B {
    address addr;
    constructor(address _addr) {
        addr = _addr;
    }

    function test() public view returns (address returnValue) {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnBytes) = addr.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("getAddress()"));
        require(success == true, "Call to getAddress() failed");
        returnValue = abi.decode(returnBytes, (address));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, `encodePacked` was a typo, I'm still learning the API, and didn't look at the code closely enough when typing out the example. However thank you for confirming the point I was asking about, which is whether the returned `bytes` should be decoded with `abi.decode`. That's what I needed to know. I'll update the question to use `encodeWithSignature` so that I don't lead anyone astray!